# Django template iterate over list inside request.GET

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My today's problem is that I've to preserve some url arguments that comes to my view in the request.

Think about the following url:

`http://localhost:8000/some-url/?myargument=hello&myargument=world&myargument=whatever`

Noticed that every argument in my url has the same key ("myargument")? Keep that in mind

In Django 1.6 if I do `{{ request.GET }}` in the template I get something like:

`<QueryDict: {u'myargument': [u'hello', u'world', u'whatever']}>`

To preserve the arguments in the next submit I want to iterate over the `request.GET` dictionary by creating a hidden field inside the `<form>` with the key-value pairs, I can do it with this code:

```
{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ key }}" value="{{ value }}">
{% endfor %}
```

It works with single values, but not in my case because I've a list with the values of the key named "myargument".

Obviously the first thing I tried was to iterate over the value by doing `{% for v in value %}` when the value is a list, but this only prints out the last item in the "value" list, in this case "whatever".

Anyone had the same problem? How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: how does it not work when you have a list? surely you dont get an error ...

Comment: You can use [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)

Comment: @Karthikr's comment is the answer.

Comment: I tried using getlist in the view and it worked, but how can I use the same function in the template? Should I do a template_tag or there is an existing way?

Comment: No, a template tag would be the way to go. Or you could send this list as a context variable, and access the list in the template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the view:

```
mydict = dict(request.GET._iterlists())
```

sent and iterate in the template:

```
<p>
{{ mydict }}
</p>

<p>
{% for k,v in mydict.iteritems %}
    {{ k }}:{% for x in v %}{{ x }},{% endfor %} <br>
{% endfor %}
</p>
```